# Are there any famous world leaders (politics, religion) who are vegan/vegetarian?

Tags: veganism, vegetarian-diet

Who are famous world leaders (politics, religion) who live on a vegan/vegetarian diet?

(Define famous: presidents, vice presidents, religious heads)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following politicians are [listed on this List of vegetarians on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vegetarians):

Hilary Benn,
Cory Booker,
Wouter Bos,
Fenner Brockway,
Kathalijne Buitenweg,
Jeremy Corbyn,
Stafford Cripps,
Morarji Desai,
Dion Graus,
Maximiliano Hernández Martínez,
Rudolf Hess,
Adolf Hitler,
Jens Holm,
Ewout Irrgang,
James Johnston,
Niko Koffeman,
Attje Kuiken,
Tzipi Livni,
Jamby Madrigal,
Cem Özdemir,
Diederik Samsom,
Gustav Struve,
Krista van Velzen,
Marijke Vos,
Marianne Thieme,
Esther Ouwehand,
Mojo Mathers ,
Natasja Oerlemans,
Bernard Weatherill,
Francisco Madero.

Most of those are not world leaders.  Adolf Hitler was leader of Germany 1933-1945.  Jeremy Corbyn is hoping to become Prime Minister of the United Kingdom in the UK elections on 8 June 2017 (in 2 days).  The others are mostly national-level parliamentarians, mostly for left-wing parties, but not (aspiring) world leaders.

Comment: To complement the answer, there's also the [Wikipedia list of vegans](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vegans) which includes former vice president of the US and climate activist Al Gore.

Mahatma Gandhi and Manmohan Singh are clearly world leaders. They are (were) also vegetarians.

Comment: Bill Clinton has gone (mostly) *vegan* and credits his new diet with saving his life.

Comment: Dennis Kucinich, who campaigned for president multiple times (and made a lot of political sense), should probably be on that list too...

Answer (score 8):

Narendra Modi the Prime Minister of India is vegetarian

http://www.financialexpress.com/opinion/narendra-modi-baba-ramdev-others-preach-vegetarianism-but-what-is-the-meat-consumption-reality-in-india/427614/

Answer (score 2):

[Janez Drnovšek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janez_Drnov%C5%A1ek), former Prime Minister and President of Slovenia, was vegan, making him the first ever vegan political leader of a country. Sadly he died in 2008.